# Plastic SCM change server/organization in Cloud

Tags: unity-game-engine, version-control, plasticscm

as I just installed Plastic SCM on my home computer, and connected through Unity, I was prompted to choose Organization. I managed to select the incorrect one and now I can't find a way to change organization within Plastic SCM.
The repo is already on the cloud according to my dashboard on the Plastic SCM website, but there is no option inside the application to switch server or organization.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to this, First, you can delete the local repo that you have cloned(the wrong one apparently as you said), or if you don't want to just create a new workspace. In the top left corner, you may find your repo name with a dropdown, click on that and create a new workspace. The new workspace dialog box will appear to select which repo you want to clone and a new workspace will be created for you with that repo.
Also there is a repositories and workspace thing in the left hand menu, if you click on the repositories and in the right hand side change the server to the desired organization. You will see a list of repos of that organization you have access to. Right Click the required repo and select create a new workspace option.